# add characters before special characters in a string

Tags: r

I would like to add some characters to a string before a special character "(" and after the special character ")"

The position of "(" and ")" changes from one string to the next.

If it helps, I tried several ways, but I don't know how to piece it back together.

```
a <- "a(b"
grepl("[[:punct:]]",  a) #special character exists
x <- "[[:punct:]]" 
image <- str_extract(a, x) #extract special character
image
```

e.g.

```
"I want to go out (i.e. now). "
```

And the result to look like:

```
"I want to go out again (i.e. now) thanks."
```

I want to add "again" and "thanks" to the sentence.

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 3):

Use `str_replace`

```
 library(stringr)
 str_replace("I want to go out (i.e. now).", "\\(", "again (") %>%
   str_replace("\\)", ") thanks")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub`.  Match the characters inside the brackets including the brackets, capture it as a group, and we replace it with adding 'again' followed by the backreference of the captureed group (`\\1`) followed by 'thanks'

```
sub("(\\([^)]+\\))\\..*", "again \\1 thanks.", str1)
#[1] "I want to go out again (i.e. now) thanks."
```

Or using two capture groups

```
sub("(\\([^)]+\\))(.*)\\s+", "again \\1 thanks\\2", str1)
#[1] "I want to go out again (i.e. now) thanks."
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "I want to go out (i.e. now). "
```

NOTE: Using only `base R`

Comment: The ")" may not necessarily be at the end of the sentence. Let me update it.

Comment: I tried this but I seem to get an error. 

    `str1 <- "I want to go out (i.e. now). " ` 
    `sub("(\\([^)]+\\))\\..*", "again \\1 thanks.",str1)`

    `Error in sub("(\\([^)]+\\))\\..*", "again \\1 thanks.", str1) :` 
  `unused argument (str1)`

Comment: @Sam I am not getting any error with the data.  I added the data as well

Comment: @akrun It works in R console itself, but using rstudio seems to throw out the error. Anyway it works. Thank you!

Comment: @Sam I am using R console as well.  Sorry, didn't test it with rstudio.  I find people upvoting the error message.  Don't know whether they have tested or blindly doing it.

Comment: @akrun no problem. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe `sub("(.*)(\\([^)]+\\))(.*)", "\\1again \\2 thanks\\3", str1)` instead of manually adding a period at the end?